# Elasticsearch PUT documents in strange order

Tags: c#, .net, browser, elasticsearch

How do set `elasticsearch` to be adding new documents with `PUT` method at the end (or the beginning).

Now it's adding new ones sometimes at the end, sometimes in the middle.

I know I can sort results by some field, but I want to see them in browser just ordered by time added without any additional parameters

Comment: Are you using any ES plugin to view your documents in your browser or are you simply querying via the address bar?

Comment: @Val Simple query http://localhost:9200/index_name/type_name/_search and JSONView extension in Chrome

Comment: ES is simply a document store, i.e. there's no inherent insertion order. I'd simply go with adding `?sort=yourdatefield:desc` to your URL and you're all set.

Comment: @Val So shouldn't it display results in different order after each query? (with sort argument of course it works well)

Comment: If you don't add any specific sort field, it will sort by score which defaults to 1.0, so the order is undefined actually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ES is simply a document store, i.e. there's no inherent insertion order. I'd simply go with adding `?sort=yourdatefield:desc` to your URL and you're all set.

If you don't add any specific sort field, it will sort by score which defaults to 1.0, so the order is undefined actually.